# Why is Xcode unable to find a GLEW dynamic library even when it is listed in the search path?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glew

*OS X Yosemite 10.10.5
Xcode 6.4*

Background: I need to use an *OpenGL loading library* such as *GLEW* because my computer doesn't support the *OpenGl* version that I am learning. So, I downloaded the GLEW-zip file and used **make** to install the dynamic library.

Right now: I am trying to use this dynamic linked library (libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib) in Xcode but I got the following error " ld: library not found for -lGLEW". However, I already told Xcode where to find it:

1. First, added **/usr/lib/libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib** to the project's Build **Phases -> Link With Binary Libraries**
2. Then, added **/usr/lib** to the project's **Build Settings -> Library Search
   Path.**
3. Finally, added the include files: **/usr/include** to the project's **Build Settings -> Header Search
   Path**

What is or could be causing this problem?

---

## SOLVED:

**PROBLEM:** the dynamic library was installed in the wrong directory `/usr/lib` . It should have been in `/usr/local/lib`. Full explanation by @Ken Thomases below.

**SOLUTION:** Changed the Makefile's `GLEW_DEST ?= /usr` to `GLEW_DEST ?= /usr/local`. Briefly mentioned here http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

Comment: Is this for iOS or MacOS?

Comment: You won't need to add `/usr/lib` or `/usr/include` as they are the standard paths.  Can you post the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libGLEW*`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I need to use /usr/include because that is where the header files for the library are located, otherwise I would need to add directly to my project directory. Output  of `ls -l /usr/lib/libGLEW*` posted above.

Comment: Show the build transcript for the step which produces the error (including the error).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YlVGMIY.png

Comment: In the future, post textual information as text, not images. Not only is it thousands of times more efficient, but one can't copy and paste from images.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will follow your advice.

Comment: @user1644677: Just FYI: You're running under MacOS-X, which means that *GLEW will give you zero extra benefits* (except it makes accessing Apple specific extensions easier, but you rarely need those). *In MacOS X the available OpenGL version is determined hard by the installed OS and the available OpenGL version matches that of the that.* **GLEW is not some kind of magic potion that "updates" your OpenGL version!** It just makes easier using what the system can do; in Windows and Linux using modern OpenGL requires some effort. In MacOS-X you just do it. No extra frills required.

Comment: @user1644677: If your MacOS-X system does not support the OpenGL version and profile you need, the only way to update the available OpenGL version is to update MacOS-X; of course your hardware must have the required capabilities as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the basis of the problem is that you installed GLEW into /usr/lib. In general, /usr/lib should be reserved for system libraries. Third-party libraries should go elsewhere, such as /usr/local/lib. The GLEW build system may allow you to specify a "prefix" of /usr/local during configure or "make install". You'd have to consult its documentation.

One reason that /usr/lib is bad is because a typical build using Xcode uses the `-isysroot` option to the link command. That redirects paths based in the standard system directories to the SDK directory, instead. So, a reference to /usr/lib is instead interpreted as a reference to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib. This is how SDK-based development is accomplished.

Obviously, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/lib doesn't include the libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib that you're attempting to link to. Hence the link error.

So, you could install GLEW to /usr/local and get it to link. However, you have to understand that that won't result in an executable you can distribute to other systems. Those other systems won't have GLEW, so your program won't be able to load. What you really need to do is build GLEW as a framework and both link against that and ship it as part of your app bundle. Or, if GLEW can't be built as a framework, you need to build it and "install" it not into the system but into a private build directory, then copy that build directory into your app bundle. You also need to make sure that the references to and among the GLEW libraries are relative to your app bundle, so it can be put anywhere on the end user's system and the references can still be resolved. (By default, the references will use absolute paths and will only be resolved if the libraries are at those exact paths.)

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the problem, in fact, it was even pointed out in the github page: https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/52  but was never corrected.

Comment: @user1644677 Hint: If someone provides a useful (in any way) answer then up vote it to encourage them to come back and help others.  If they provide what you consider the answer then you should accept the answer as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe SO users need (15 <= reputation) for their votes to show up.